# Pi Zero splash screen

Tags: boot, pi-zero

I created a custom splash screen on a Pi 3 B+, when I transfer the card over to my Pi zero, the splash screen does not display, only 3 small squares about 2/3 of the way down the screen.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It's hard to say what you're missing with no clue about what you've done! :-) Describe what steps you have taken and perhaps someone will be able to see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: There's not enough RAM on a Zero so the splash screen never runs. That's a deliberate choice by the developer.